# Firefox breaking up from when using display: inline-block;

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I am currently having a strange cross-browser problem.

After 2.5 seconds a form drops in. This is working well in IE and Chrome, but somehow it is not in FF. This is the HTML part

```
<div id="holder"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="main"></a></div><div id="dropDiv"><form>
<input class="geld-input" type="text" name="email" value="Vul hier je e-mail in en krijg direct toegang tot de geheime pagina..." value="Vul hier je e-mail in en krijg direct toegang tot de geheime pagina..." onclick="if(this.value=='Vul hier je e-mail in en krijg direct toegang tot de geheime pagina...')this.value='';this.focus();" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Vul hier je e-mail in en krijg direct toegang tot de geheime pagina...';" tabindex="501"  /><input class="geld-submit" type="submit" value="Krijg Direct Toegang" /></form></div></div>
```

and here is the CSS part:

```
#holder { position: absolute; top: 550px;  margin:0 auto; width:100%; display: inline-block;}
#dropDiv {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
}
```

Now if I delete the "display:inline-block" part on the #holder div, then it works in FF, IE but not in chrome.

If you want to view the full source: http://www.luukratief.com/lander

Could someone tell what the way to go is to make this cross-browser?

Comment: Please include the code in your post. It's not acceptable for your question to depend on an external link to live code that will be changed as soon as you find a fix. Your question needs to remain relevant even after you've solved your problem.

Comment: @meagar I am really sorry. Been a while since I have been on stackoverflow. I now included the HTML code and CSS code. Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting a `left` value on `#holder`.  That means the static position is used, but the spec doesn't quite define what that is in various edge cases.  Furthermore, browsers differ in their behavior for how it's computed, depending on what was easiest to implement, since the spec doesn't define the behavior anyway.

You probably want to do something like `left: 0`.